# conformal invariance of Dirichlet Integral

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry

I am reading one of Escobar's papers and I am stuck at the following (I am new to this area of math). Let $(M^{2},g_{0})$ be a compact manifold with boundary. Let $g=e^{2f}g_{0}$ be a metric conformally related to the metric $g_{0}$. I want to justify why
$$\int_{M}|\nabla\varphi|^{2}_{g}dV_{g}=\int_{M}|\nabla\varphi|^{2}_{g_{0}}dV_{0}.$$
Where $\varphi\in C^{1}(\bar{M}).$

Escobar justified it by saying that the Dirichlet integral is a conformal invariant. However, I am working on proving this and so far I have not been able to prove it. I have tried different things but the closest I have gotten is
$$\int_{M}|\nabla\varphi|^{2}_{g}dV_{g}=\int_{M}e^{4f}|\nabla\varphi|^{2}_{g_{0}}dV_{0}.$$

Any help, suggestion or the pointing out of a reference where I can read more about this (the easiest to understand the better) would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n = \dim(M)$. In coordinates, we have
$$\det G = e^{2nf} \det G_0,$$
$$dV_g = e^{nf} dV_0,$$
$$\nabla_g \phi = G^{-1}\partial \phi,$$
$$|\nabla_g \phi|^2 = \langle \nabla_g \phi, G \nabla_g \phi \rangle = \langle \partial \phi, G^{-1}\partial \phi \rangle = e^{-2f}|\nabla_{g_0} \phi|^2,$$
$$|\nabla_g \phi|^2 dV_g = e^{(n - 2)f}|\nabla_{g_0} \phi|^2 dV_0.$$
So if $n = 2$, then the integral is indeed a conformal invariant.